# Handlebars template not displaying context data

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to build a quiz application using Node express and Handlebars as the templating engine.

I have the following template:

```
<div id="quiz">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row" id="quiz-header-row"> 
             <div>
                <div id="question-title"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="quiz-choices-row"> 
            <div id="choices"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" id="quiz-footer-row"> 
            <button id="quiz-next-btn" class="btn btn-success">Next</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Template  -->
<script id="choices-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>\{{choices}}</div>
    <div>
        {{#each choices}}
        <a href="#"">{{this}}</a>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

If I do not use the backslash before curly braces, handlebars displays an empty string and thus I cannot write this:

```
<div>{{choices}}</div>
```

Found on handlebars official website that I have to use: **\{{choices}}**.

The javascript that fills the template with data:

```
renderChoices: function() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#choices-template').html());

    var context = {
        // array of quiz item choices
        choices: Quiz.questions[Quiz.currentIndex].choices
    };

    $('#choices').html(template(context));
},
```

The issue I am facing is the **#each** block that does not display anything. The backslash before **{{#each choices}}** cannot be used as in the example above because the server throws "server internal error: 500".

This is the console logged context:
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yyvz.png)

The fiddle below works as needed and does not need the backslashes

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maqpej0h/).

But the exact same code I run in my project using Node does not display anything written inside the **#each** block.

I have Handlebars both on the server (express-handlebars) and on the client. Considering the results, I am doing something the wrong way.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Fixed by precompiling the templates in external files and including them as scripts in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
{{#each choices as |choice|}}
    <a href="#">{{choice}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

And make sure `choices` is populated as you expect.

Comment: choices array is populated (logging context in the console inside "renderChoices" function  displays expected result). Unfortunately, it does not display anything even when writing it the way you suggested. Thank you anyway.

Comment: what version of handlebars are you using?  Also if you can post what you are seeing from the log that may be helpful

Comment: Handlebars version is 4.0.5

Comment: Is anything being rendered inside the 'each'? (like an empty html a tag?)  Have you tried it without the '<div>\{{choices}}</div>' ? Are you seeing any other errors?  The more info the better!  If you can make a sample jsfiddle that would be best.

Comment: Life saver. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

i just tried to execute your code it's printing the data, i have used jquery-2.2.1 and handlebars 2.0.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
   <script id="address-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     <div>
        {{#each choices}}
          <a href="#"">{{this}}</a>
        {{/each}}
     </div>
   </script>
   <!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
   <div class="content-placeholder"></div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js">
 </script>
   <script>          

    $(function () {
      // Grab the template script
      var theTemplateScript = $("#address-template").html();

      // Compile the template
      var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

      // Define our data object
      var context={
        choices: ["choice1","choice2","choice3"]
      };

      // Pass our data to the template
      var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context);

      // Add the compiled html to the page
      $('.content-placeholder').html(theCompiledHtml);
      });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/uHfj0enz4mXjSLeO8qqN?p=preview) to plunker, i also tried with handlebars 4.0.3 and jquery 3.1.1 it's running fine.